# VB delete selection not working

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

In my macro i need to resize a cell and delete the selection . I have tried everything but it just wont work. It keeps giving me object defined error on my `ActiveCell.resize` line. I have changed that line many times to no avail. Please help, this is suppose to be simple.

```
Sub CovDatesAndDeletes()
    'shortcut ctrl + b

    Dim SrchRng As Range
    Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:C62000")


    For Each Source In SrchRng
        If Source.Text Like "ACCUM_CLM" Then
            Source.Activate
            ActiveCell.Resize(25, -2).Select
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp     
        End If
    Next Source 

End Sub
```

Comment: If it is a macro, then it is not vb.net. Consider removing the `vb.net` tag. It is misleading. Can you tell us what you tried (What is "everything"?)? Have you tried searching on `object defined error`? Take a look at [Resize()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa176182(v=office.11).aspx). That may help you.

Comment: Do you need to resize the cell if you are deleting it?

Comment: yes i need to resize so I delete all the cells that go with it

Answer (score 0):

ActiveCell.Resize resizes a range object, not a cell as you mentioned in your question. You need to clarify what you are trying to do (I can't ask this in comments - not enough rep).

It seems like you want to search for a cell in your range containing the string ACCUM_CLM. When found, extend the range selection 25 rows down, but not to include columns B and C, delete the selection contents and move the content below the deletion up to where you started. If this is what you want to do, then change your code as follows:

```
If Source.Text Like "ACCUM_CLM" Then
    Source.Resize(25).Select
    Source.Delete (xlUp)
End If
```

Comment: I do need it to include columns b and c

Comment: Then change .Resize(25) to .Resize(25,3). The -2 in your original code will cause an error. Better yet, change Source.Resize(25).Select to Source.Resize(25,3).Delete and remove the second line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to get a feel for what you are trying to do from the above code - can you try replacing ActiveCell.Resize(25, -2).Select with Range("A" & Activecell.row).Resize(25, 3).Select and feedback on whether this actually allows to solve any problem here?